# How to make date to date filter bar in Python, Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How can I make a date filter bar like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3mfH.png), using Python and Flask in my web app? I want to display a table with data from my postgresql db for instance, ONLY from 12.02.2002  to 05.05.2020.

Comment: What have you tried until now? Add some code and explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: I haven't tried too much because I don't even know how to start with it. I found much information on the internet but not specifically about that type of filtering.